# Unable to run npm i

Tags: node.js, npm, debian, npm-install

I am trying to use [micromdm-ui](https://github.com/mosen/micromdm-ui) but it keeps on giving me errors when trying to run npm i

This is the output:

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'karma@1.7.1',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '0.10 || 0.12 || 4 || 5 || 6 || 7 || 8' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v19.2.0', npm: '8.19.3' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'podda@1.2.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { npm: '^3.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v19.2.0', npm: '8.19.3' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'react-komposer@2.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { npm: '^3.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v19.2.0', npm: '8.19.3' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'react-stubber@1.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { npm: '^3.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v19.2.0', npm: '8.19.3' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated flatten@1.0.3: flatten is deprecated in favor of utility frameworks such as lodash.
npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2017@6.24.1:   Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read https://babeljs.io/env to update!
npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2016@6.24.1:   Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read https://babeljs.io/env to update!
npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-latest@6.16.0: We're super   excited that you're trying to use ES2017+ syntax, but instead of making more yearly presets  , Babel now has a better preset that we recommend you use instead: npm install babel-preset-env --save-dev. preset-env without options will compile ES2015+ down to ES5 just like using all the presets together and thus is more future proof. It also allows you to target specific browsers so that Babel can do less work and you can ship native ES2015+ to user  ! We are also in the process of releasing v7, so please give http://babeljs.io/blog/2017/09/12/planning-for-7.0 a read and help test it out in beta! Thanks so much for using Babel , please give us a follow on Twitter @babeljs for news on Babel, join slack.babeljs.io for discussion/development and help support the project at opencollective.com/babel
npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1:   Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read https://babeljs.io/env to update!
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated json3@3.3.2: Please use the native JSON object instead of JSON 3
npm WARN deprecated formatio@1.1.1: This package is unmaintained. Use @sinonjs/formatio instead
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@1.7.0: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated extract-text-webpack-plugin@1.0.1: Deprecated. Please use https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin
npm WARN deprecated samsam@1.1.2: This package has been deprecated in favour of @sinonjs/samsam
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.3.3: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
npm WARN deprecated babel-eslint@7.2.3: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated array.prototype.flatten@1.2.1: This method has been renamed to "flat" - please use `array.prototype.flat` instead
npm WARN deprecated uuid@2.0.3: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.16: this package is now deprecated
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated svgo@0.7.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated istanbul@0.4.5: This module is no longer maintained, try this instead:
npm WARN deprecated   npm i nyc
npm WARN deprecated Visit https://istanbul.js.org/integrations for other alternatives.
npm WARN deprecated log4js@0.6.38: 0.x is no longer supported. Please upgrade to 6.x or higher.
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /root/micromdm-ui/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /usr/bin/node /root/micromdm-ui/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/usr/bin/node',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/root/micromdm-ui/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@19.2.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python2 /usr/bin/python2
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python2 -c "import sys; print "2.7.18
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 19.2.0
npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '19.2.0' ]
npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "19.2.0"
npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 19.2.0
npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 19.2.0
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /root/micromdm-ui/node_modules/node-sass/build
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? /root/micromdm-ui/node_modules/node-sass/build
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: /root/micromdm-ui/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: /root/micromdm-ui/node_modules/node-sass/config.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: /root/micromdm-ui/node_modules/node-sass/common.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "make"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python2
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/root/micromdm-ui/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/root/micromdm-ui/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/root/micromdm-ui/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/root/.node-gyp/19.2.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/root/.node-gyp/19.2.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/root/micromdm-ui/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/root/.node-gyp/19.2.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/root/micromdm-ui/node_modules/node-sass',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp: Undefined variable standalone_static_library in binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/root/micromdm-ui/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:345:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:293:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.10.0-19-amd64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/root/micromdm-ui/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /root/micromdm-ui/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v19.2.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-12-05T08_42_41_013Z-debug-0.log
root@debian:~/micromdm-ui#
```

I read a few threads from diffrent forums even here and I still keep on getting the same error everything i try

The current version of NodeJS installed is: 8.19.3 I got Python 2 & 3 installed

I really don't know what to do I thank everyone in advance for reading and giving me sugestions on how to fix this error

Answer (score 0):

from the error , it looks like you are using node 19.2.0

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'karma@1.7.1',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '0.10 || 0.12 || 4 || 5 || 6 || 7 || 8' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v19.2.0', npm: '8.19.3' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
```

Comment: weird I installed the 18 version

Comment: I reinstalled it and now I recceive this [error](https://pastebin.com/HeSt3bcA)